# How to build apk with Buildozer and extra arguments?

Tags: kivy

How can i run buildozer with extra arguments on the cmd?

`buildozer android_new debug p4a --permission VIBRATE` 
this is an example,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- try reading buildozer github acc's readme https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/README.rst
- the following link will also aid you https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/